# Unable to connect Redis Cache server using ServiceStack.Redis library

Tags: azure, caching, redis, servicestack.redis

I have install `PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.Redis` and used following code to connect azure redis cache.

I think I missed connection string as I have not given `PRIMARY KEY` in `host`

```
string host = "mydemo.redis.cache.windows.net";
            var redisManager = new PooledRedisClientManager(host);
            using (var redisClient = redisManager.GetClient())
            {
                IRedisTypedClient<Customer> redis = redisClient.As<Customer>();
```

Getting error :

> {"could not connect to redis Instance at
>   mydemo.redis.cache.windows.net:6379"}
>
> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond 11.22.216.225:6379

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic network connection error. You need to ensure that you have access to connect to TCP port 6379 on `mydemo.redis.cache.windows.net` (11.22.216.225:6379) and open up any firewall rules as necessary.

You can test TCP connections with telnet or by running `redis-cli.exe` (from [redis-windows](https://github.com/ServiceStack/redis-windows)) on the same server you're trying to use [ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis), e.g:

```
redis-cli -h 11.22.216.225 -p 6379
```

### [SSL Redis Connections to Azure Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Secure-SSL-Redis-connections-to-Azure-Redis#configuring-our-apphost)

The connection string if you're [trying to connect to a redis-server on Azure](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Secure-SSL-Redis-connections-to-Azure-Redis) is typically in the format:

```
{AzureRedisKey}@servicestackdemo.redis.cache.windows.net?ssl=true
```

The `?ssl=true` option says to use SSL on the default port Azure SSL port **6380**.